# Are there any benefits of registering my udf in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a python function such as:

```
 def blank_as_null(x):
     return when(col(x) != "", col(x)).otherwise(None)
```

I am using this function without running `udf(blank_as_null, StringType())` as suggested in the documentation: http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html or in this video: https://youtu.be/AsW0QzbYVow?t=42m33s (at 42:33 you can see the code calling the `udf` function)

And then i do something like:

`myData.withColumn('myColumn', blank_as_null('myColumn'))`

would there be any benefit of registering the python function first? Under what conditions is the registering beneficial? When it doesn't matter? Or is the registering done automagically under the hood?

Comment: You use a `udf` when you want to use pure python operations- what you're doing here is not considered a `udf`- you just wrapped some of the API functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you are mixing two different transformations: PySpark API ones and UDFs:

- A PySpark API transformation (for lack of a better name) is anything that uses the already existing functionality provided by PySpark. These map to the Scala API, and run natively in the JVM. This is what you are using in your example code (`when`, `otherwise` and the like).
- The Spark API cannot cover every single transformation, so Spark allows programmers to define their own ones, and that is what a User Defined Function (UDF) is. You need to declare and register them in advance so that Spark knows what input and output data it expects. The advantage of this mechanism is that you can define any transformation without the limitations of the Spark API. However, they will not have a JVM counterpart, and thus will be executed in pure Python, adding a communication overhead between the JVM and the Python executors.

You should always aim for the first type of transformations due to performance reasons, but if what you are trying to achieve is not feasible using the Spark API, your only choice are UDFs.

Comment: Additionally, when using the `udf()` function you need to use the return value as the parameter that you pass to `withColumn`! In this case it works because your function uses the Spark API (and it would not work with the return value of `udf()`).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! One a bit unrelated question, if i may: in the same video as i linked above ( https://youtu.be/AsW0QzbYVow?t=43m56s ) the guy says that it is faster to create a new object (rename dataframe) when making some transformation (i.e. `df2 = df1.withColumn('a', myFunction('b'))` should be faster than `df1 = df1.withColumn('a', myFunction('b'))`). Is this true even in the current versions of the api? What would be the reason for such a behavior?

Comment: I find that a bit odd, as transformations (`withColumn`, `select`...) do not perform any computation, but rather define how the data is processed. When calling an action (such as `collect` or `show`), the transformation graph is traversed, optimized and then finally evaluated. As such, I am a bit skeptical about the statement in the video (but you can just try it out!). Nevertheless, I think it is best to use a new variable for each transformation, as they uniquely identify each step of your processing pipeline, making it easier to understand, refactor and test.