# How to register a complex function as the below as UDF in PYSPARK?

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks

I have a function that takes a dataframe as a parameter and calculates the NULL value counts and NULL value percentage and returns a dataframe with column_name, null value count and null percentages. How can I register it as UDF in pyspark so that I can use the spark's processing advantage. I am using spark 3.3.0

This is my function:

[image]

I could'nt find any method or implementation for complex functions and functions that run on whole dataframe.

Comment: Yes, I am using azure databricks, spark 3.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you made is not UDF. You are using spark methods inside the function so it is not UDF. Spark methods are already optimized for datasets.

Answer (score 1):

- I have tried to register the UDF while trying to do so I have
  encountered **Serialization Issues**,**Missing GROUP BY
  Clause**,**Incompatible Data Types** and **Unsupported Functions**
- I tried to register the function using Pandas UDF in PySpark and apply it to the whole DataFrame
- Spark **UDF**s might not handle complex objects or Spark-specific objects properly.

I have tried below approach
Created a function to get null count and percentage and called the function

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, round
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("example") \
    .getOrCreate()
data = [(1, "Alice", 30, None),
        (2, "Bob", None, 70),
        (3, "Carol", 25, 80)]
columns = ['id', 'name', 'age', 'score']
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
def get_null_count_and_percentage(df):
    global is_null_value_appended
    columnList = df.columns
    total_count = df.count()
    null_counts = []
    for column_to_check in columnList:
        null_count = df.filter(col(column_to_check).isNull()).count()
        null_percentage = (null_count / total_count) * 100
        null_counts.append((column_to_check, null_count, null_percentage))
    result_df_count = spark.createDataFrame(null_counts, schema=['column_name', 'null_counts', 'null_percentage'])
    result_df_count = result_df_count.withColumn("null_percentage", round(col("null_percentage"), 2))
    return result_df_count
result_df = get_null_count_and_percentage(df)
result_df.show()
```

[image]

- The above code is  Defining Function - get_null_count_and_percentage that takes a DataFrame, df, as an argument.
- This function calculates the count and percentage of null values in each column of the DataFrame.
- The list of column names is extracted using df.columns.
- The total count of rows in the DataFrame is obtained using
  `df.count()`
- An empty list null_counts is initialized to store the null counts and percentages for each column.
- loop iterates through each column, and the count of null values is obtained using the filter method combined with `col(column_to_check).isNull()`.
- The percentage of null values for each column is calculated and stored in the null_counts list as tuples.
- A new DataFrame, result_df_count, is created using
  spark.createDataFrame by passing the null_counts list, and the schema is defined as `['column_name', 'null_counts', 'null_percentage']`.
- The null_percentage column in the DataFrame is rounded to two decimal places using the withColumn and round functions.
- The main purpose of this script is to calculate the count and
  percentage of null values for each column in the DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, but I read an answer here on another post that the function I created is not UDF. I have just used spark APIs and wrapped them in a function. So there is no need to register because the spark API's already run on JVM and are optimized for large datasets. On the other hand, UDFs are those that do not use any predefined spark APIs and use pure Python or a different language. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52609143/are-there-any-benefits-of-registering-my-udf-in-pyspark) to that answer

Comment: The function you made is not UDF. You are using spark methods inside the function so it is not UDF. Spark methods are already optimized for datasets.